# Data Submited from APP Differs from Php local Script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, cordova

I'm currently working on a project with Phonegap, PHP and MySQL for a Hybrid App, the API involves sending an email and with the data fill a procedure call to save it on the database (MySQL), the email is OK but I'm having issues saving the data on MySQL, I created a single file with a form to test the API and worked, what I noticed is that when I use the APP to send data to API, the data comes with special characters like @, and when I use the form the data cames for example with %40 (ASCII code for @) and the procedure call works fine.

The codes are below, the Test Code and also the API code, the API Version works with the data coming to PHP from a JSON send from the APP.

**API Version**

```
 <?php

Include("dbconect.php"); #DB Connector

if (!empty($_GET)) {

/* Recuperando Dados do GET */
$DestinoEmail = "webmaster@testfab.com"; //Destino para o Email de   Notificação

$NomeCompleto  = $_GET['Nome'];
$TelefoneFixo  = $_GET['TelefoneFixo'];
$TelefoneMovel = $_GET['TelefoneMovel'];
$email       = $_GET['Mail'];
$cor           = $_GET['CorSelecionada'];
$Rg         = $_GET['NumeroRG'];
$cep           = $_GET['NumeroCEP'];
$assunto       = $_GET['AssuntoEmail'];
$descricao   = $_GET['descricaoEmail'];
$mobileID     = $_GET['MobileReg'];
$sexo         = $_GET['Sex'];
$nCasa       = "0";

/* Envia o email notificando */

#Corpo do Email
$msg= "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset='utf-8'>
          <style type='text/css'>
          body {

           color: #3A6EA5;
          }

          h5 {
              background-color: #3A6EA5;
              padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
              width: 950px;
          }
          </style>
       </head>
         <body>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Prezado $NomeCompleto,</p>
          <p>Seu Teste foi encaminhado com sucesso para nossa linha , favor aguarde retorno.</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </body>
    </html>";

# Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@testemat.com>' . "\r\n";
$assuntoMail = "Teste de Material";
#Codificar Assunto para aceitar os acentos
$assunto_codificado = sprintf('=?%s?%s?%s?=', 'UTF-8', 'B', base64_encode($assuntoMail));
#Quebra de Linha caso a linha ultrapasse 70 caracteres
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
#Envio do Email
mail($DestinoEmail,$assunto_codificado ,$msg,$headers);

/*  Executar a Proc para armazenar os dados    */

$ncasa = "0";
$sth = $db->prepare('CALL    PR_REGISTER_REPORT(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,@out)');
$sth->bindParam(1,  $NomeCompleto, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(2,  $TelefoneFixo, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(3,  $TelefoneMovel, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(4,  $email, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(5,  $cor, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(6,  $Rg, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(7,  $cep, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(8,  $ncasa, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(9,  $mobileID, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(10, $sexo, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(11, $assunto, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(12, $descricao, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->execute();

//Retorno OK para o APP
$resultados["validate"] = "ok";
$resultadosJson = json_encode($resultados);
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $resultadosJson . ');';

}else{

Echo "Interface Somente com APP";

}

?>
```

**Testing Version (test-process.php)**

```
<?php

  Include("dbconect.php"); #DB Connector

  if (!empty($_GET)) {

  /* Recuperando Dados do GET */
  $DestinoEmail = "webmaster@testfab.com"; //Destino para o Email de       Notificação

  $NomeCompleto  = $_GET['Nome'];
  $TelefoneFixo  = $_GET['TelefoneFixo'];
  $TelefoneMovel = $_GET['TelefoneMovel'];
  $email         = $_GET['Mail'];
  $cor         = $_GET['CorSelecionada'];
  $Rg           = $_GET['NumeroRG'];
  $cep         = $_GET['NumeroCEP'];
  $assunto     = $_GET['AssuntoEmail'];
  $descricao     = $_GET['descricaoEmail'];
  $mobileID   = $_GET['MobileReg'];
  $sexo       = $_GET['Sex'];
  $nCasa         = "0";

  /* Envia o email notificando */

  #Corpo do Email
  $msg= "<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset='utf-8'>
          <style type='text/css'>
          body {

           color: #3A6EA5;
          }

          h5 {
              background-color: #3A6EA5;
              padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
              width: 950px;
          }
          </style>
       </head>
         <body>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Prezado $NomeCompleto,</p>
          <p>Seu Teste foi encaminhado com sucesso para nossa linha , favor aguarde retorno.</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </body>
    </html>";

# Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@testemat.com>' . "\r\n";
$assuntoMail = "Teste de Material";
#Codificar Assunto para aceitar os acentos
$assunto_codificado = sprintf('=?%s?%s?%s?=', 'UTF-8', 'B', base64_encode($assuntoMail));
#Quebra de Linha caso a linha ultrapasse 70 caracteres
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
#Envio do Email
mail($DestinoEmail,$assunto_codificado ,$msg,$headers);

/*  Executar a Proc para armazenar os dados    */

$ncasa = "0";
$sth = $db->prepare('CALL    PR_REGISTER_REPORT(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,@out)');
$sth->bindParam(1,  $NomeCompleto, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(2,  $TelefoneFixo, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(3,  $TelefoneMovel, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(4,  $email, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(5,  $cor, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(6,  $Rg, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(7,  $cep, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(8,  $ncasa, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(9,  $mobileID, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(10, $sexo, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(11, $assunto, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->bindParam(12, $descricao, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->execute();

//Retorno OK para o APP
$resultados["validate"] = "ok";
$resultadosJson = json_encode($resultados);
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $resultadosJson . ');';

}else{

echo"

<form action='test-process.php' method='get'>
Nome Completo:<br>
<input type='text' name='Nome' value=''><br>
Telefone Fixo:<br>
<input type='text' name='TelefoneFixo' value=''><br>
 Telefone Movel:<br>
<input type='text' name='TelefoneMovel' value=''><br>
  Email:<br>
<input type='text' name='Mail' value=''><br>
 Cor:<br>
<input type='text' name='CorSelecionada' value=''><br>
 NumeroRG:<br>
<input type='text' name='NumeroRG' value=''><br>
NumeroCEP:<br>
<input type='text' name='NumeroCEP' value=''><br>
 AssuntoEmail:<br>
<input type='text' name='AssuntoEmail' value=''><br>
  DescricaoEmail:<br>
<input type='text' name='descricaoEmail' value=''><br>
  MobileReg:<br>
<input type='text' name='MobileReg' value=''><br>
Sex:<br>
<input type='text' name='Sex' value=''><br>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>";

}

?>
```

Any suggestion?

> Already tried to force the utf8_encode($foo);
>   not working yet =(

Comment: Why do you use a GET-request to send data that will be stored in a DB and be sent in an email? I think POST would be more appropriate (and you wouldn't get the same url-encoding issues).

Comment: Too bad I can only upvote @MagnusEriksson comment more than once.  This is the very first thing you should do.

Comment: Ok! i will give it a try!

Comment: nope not working yet =(

Comment: This is the ajax call:

  $.ajax({ 
   type: "POST",
   url: 'url/Email.php?jsoncallback=?',
   crossDomain: true,
   beforeSend : function() {alert("Carregando");},
      complete   : function() {alert("Enviado");},
   dataType   : 'json',
   data: { ...content...